# IF function in Excel troubleshooting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013

im having trouble using the IF function. Basically i want to be able to create a cell that multiples several other cells as well as ADDS another. So far the formula works but if i do not enter any information into the other cells it shows a value of '1' which is really annoying. How can i edit my formula to avoid the '1'?

This is the formula i'm using at the moment that i got off another website:

```
IF(G5="",1,G5) * IF(H5="",1,H5) +I5 *IF(G5&H5="",0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding I5 at the end.  I would think that you could change your IF statements to use 0 instead of 1.

```
IF(G5="",0,G5) * IF(H5="",0,H5) +I5 *IF(G5&H5="",0,1)
```

However, if you want the result to be blank instead of zero (because I5 could be blank), you would need to rearrange your formula to test if G5 or H5 are blank already.

```
IF(G5="" OR H5="","",G5 * H5) +I5
```

If you would like to be able to have blank values for G5 or H5, you should avoid doing the multiplication.  You could use another embeddded IF.

```
IF(G5="" OR H5="",(IF G5="",H5,G5)),G5 * H5) +I5
```

if G5 is blank or H5 is blank, you cannot multiply them.  If G5 is blank, then use H5 (regarless of whether H5 is blank).  If G5 and H5 are not blank, then multiply them.  Add I5, regardless of its content.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply tgolisch. The formula works great if i input all 3 values, but i want it to be able to work if i only choose to enter in 2 or 1 values (eg. just a number in G5 or H5) . Sorry to be a pain in the ass but I would be so thankfull if you could help me out!!!

Comment: I added a third formula.  It should handle blank values for G5 and H5 better.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but am not sure!) this may suit:

```
=IF(OR(G5="",H5=""),"",G5*H5+I5)
```

It is only a little more than half the number of characters of the formula you got off another website, which makes me wonder whether that was trying to achieve something slightly different (such as a `1` for default!), or I have misunderstood your requirement.

The above is a standard [IF](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php) statement:

> IF( condition, [value_if_true], [value_if_false] )

that tests for either of G5 or H5 being blank with [OR](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or.php). If either is blank the condition is met and the value _if_true is returned (ie `""` -  (blank) ).

Otherwise the test has failed (the condition is false) so the alternative, of the product of G5 and H5 is returned, added to I5.

With the above, I5 will not be returned on its own (even if only one of G5 and H5 is blank).